# strange Behaviour with Dropdown in IE8

Tags: html

I am Binding some values from DB and displaying into a Drop down. However I am facing a issue doing so.

Let's use the value `cricketisgoodgame.it` as an example. This is displaying clearly in IE9 but in IE8 it only displays part of the value, something like `cricketisgo.`

Any suggestion would be most welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be most helpful if you provided us with the code you are running, and what you have tried so far. It is very hard to provide help when we have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass = "drpdown" Width = "92%">
        </asp:DropDownList> actually well i dont have the proper code..couldn't post..just a suggestion required.is there any browser issue?